# Access 2016 drop-down list appearing in Reports and Queries

Tags: ms-access

In Access 2016 I have a table called 'Orders'.

I also have a Form (also called 'Orders') that we use to enter order information. On the form, one field in particular ('Company') is a drop-down list. The control source is a second table called 'Companies'. And the Row Source is a SQL Query:

`SELECT [Companies].[ID], [Companies].[CompanyName] FROM Companies ORDER BY [CompanyName];`

So, when the user is entering an order into the Form, he/she can select the company name from this drop-down list and it in turn updates the Orders table. All basic stuff, and it works fine.

Next, I created a query (also called 'Orders') and it is based off of the Orders table.

When I run the query in Access and view it as a Datasheet, I was surprised to notice that the Company field (IN THE QUERY datasheet) is a drop-down list. Not only that, it even lets me change the value - right here in the query! If I view the SQL for this query, I can see that it is a SELECT query. In my mind, a SELECT query is read only. So my questions are - What's a drop-down list doing in a Query, and WHY does Access let me edit the values directly in the query? Isn't this supposed to be read only?

Next question:
After verifying that all of the data I need is in the Orders query, I then created a report (called 'All Orders') and the control source for this report is the Orders query. (not the table).

When I view the Report in Design view, there's the drop-down list again. Why? I am just looking to add the Company name that the user selected when they completed the form. I realize that the form Control for entering that data (on the FORM) is a drop-down list. But here I am building a report and I just want the VALUE to appear here. Not the drop down control? (I know that when I print the report or view it on the screen, the drop-down boxes go away and all I see is the actual text). But my question is - WHY is Access showing me a drop-down list control on a report? and in a select query? The query and the report are no place for editing data. I just want the value that was selected.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've defined the lookup list in the table. If you do so, it propagates to queries and new reports and forms, and will be the default way to view the data everywhere you've placed it.

Open your table in design view, and change the display control for your field back to text box. Note that any forms and reports will need to be edited or recreated, for queries the change should propagate.

[image]